# AJAX callback function intermittently fails to add GET parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, callback

I have a `<ul>` with each `<li>` having an id like `<li id='entry24'>`.  When one is clicked, I need to query the server for that entries information, by sending a get request to `/query/getEntry/id=24`.

Using this code:

```
for(var entry = 0; entry < entryIds.length; entry++) {
    $("#entry" + entryIds[entry]).click(function() {
        $.get(
            "/query/getEntry",
            {id: entryIds[entry]},
            getEntryCallback,
            "html"
        )
    });
}
```

I found that every request was sending the same id - the id of the last entry.  After some research, I modified my code to this:

```
for(var entry = 0; entry < entryIds.length; entry++) {
    var entryId = entryIds[entry];
    $("#entry" + entryId).click(function(event) {
        $.get(
            "/query/getEntry",
            {id: event.target.id.replace("entry", "")},
            getEntryCallback,
            "html"
        )
    });
}
```

which works better (each `<li>` sends the correct id).  However, looking at the Firebug console I can see requests being made with each click, but about 75% of the time they show `/query/getEntry/id=` in red.. meaning the id wasn't actually sent and I didn't get the results I was expecting.

I can confirm that every `<li>` DOES have an appropriate `id` field.

Any help/advice MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Your code seems like it should work. Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where it fails?

Comment: Note that jQuery provides `this` as an alias to the listening element: `this.id.replace(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    entryid = $(this).attr('title');
    $.get(
        "/query/getEntry",
        {id: entryid.replace("entry", "")},
        getEntryCallback,
        "html"
    )
});
```

For your html, define the entry id in a title attribute for all `<li>`s in your `<ul>`

This should work if am not wrong since the AJAX function is called only when an `<li>` is clicked and the title attribute is unique to each `<li>` resulting in a unique id each time.

Comment: Doesn't explain why OP's code sometimes fails, but still provides a viable alternative. +1

Comment: I used ul/li in my question for simplicity, but this code works perfectly: $(".columnData.entryTable > h3").click(function() {$.get("/query/getEntry",{id: this.id.replace("entry", "")},getEntryCallback,"html")}); I'd love to know why...

Comment: @AlexMcMillan `event.target` can be a child of `this` (the element it bubbled from) instead of `this` itself, so I think this is the reason `element.target` sometimes failed.

Answer (score 2):

this is best solution,please look to this:

```
$("li[id^='entry']").on("click",function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(5);
    $.get(
        "/query/getEntry",
        {id: id},
        getEntryCallback,
        "html"
    );
});
```

Comment: I would hardly call it the best solution (that's very bold), but it works. +1

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure precisely why you're encountering that issue with your `<li>`s. However, try doing this:

```
for(var entry = 0; entry < entryIds.length; entry++) {
    var entryId = entryIds[entry];
    $("#entry" + entryId).click(function(event) {
        $.get(
            "/query/getEntry",
            {id: entryId},
            getEntryCallback,
            "html"
        )
    });
}
```

This should be forming a closure around the `entryId` variable at the time that the onclick handler is defined, such that the proper id is retained for each entry.

Comment: `var` is always scoped to the nearest enclosing `function`. It will get reused.

Comment: Interesting. I could swear I've done similar in the past to form a closure, but testing now it isn't working. My mistake.

Comment: It should work with an extra closing function (then it's a good solution and you deserve the credit).